# I get Error "Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains" when filtering on views.py from models.py

Tags: python, django

I want to filter　'language' from the models.py
but it said there is Error.

*" raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookup_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains"*

I don't know why just 'language' throws this error.
When I try to filter 'genre', 'title', I don't see the Error on the terminal.

What could be the problem/solution?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
import uuid

class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter a book genre (e.g. Science Fiction)')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                            help_text="Enter the book's natural language (e.g. English, French, Japanese etc.)")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Enter a brief description of the book')
    isbn = models.CharField('ISBN', max_length=13, help_text='13 Character <a href="https://www.isbn-international.org/content/what-isbn">ISBN number</a>')
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text='Select a genre for this book')
    language = models.ForeignKey('Language', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('book-detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class BookInstance(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular book across whole library')
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    imprint = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    due_back = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    LOAN_STATUS = (
        ('m', 'Maintenance'),
        ('o', 'On loan'),
        ('a', 'Available'),
        ('r', 'Reserved'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=LOAN_STATUS,
        blank=True,
        default='m',
        help_text='Book availability',
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['due_back']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} ({self.book.title})'


class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField('Died', null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('author-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.last_name}, {self.first_name}'

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['last_name']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Book, Author, BookInstance, Genre
from django.views import generic

def index(request):

    num_books = Book.objects.all().count()
    num_instances = BookInstance.objects.all().count()
    num_instances_available = BookInstance.objects.filter(status__exact='a').count()
    num_authors = Author.objects.count()

    context = {
        'num_books': num_books,
        'num_instances': num_instances,
        'num_instances_available': num_instances_available,
        'num_authors': num_authors,
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)

class BookListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book
    template_name = "catalog/book_list.html"

    queryset = Book.objects.filter(language__icontains='Hebrew')


class BookDetailView(generic.ListView):

    model = Book


class BokListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book


    template_name = "catalog/bok_list.html"

class BokDetailView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book

class BkListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book
    template_name = "catalog/bk_list.html"

class BkDetailView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book

class AuthorListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Author

class AuthorDetailView(generic.ListView):
    model = Author
```

Comment: As you are new on Stack Overflow, do not forget to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `queryset = Book.objects.filter(language__icontains='Hebrew')`
with `queryset = Book.objects.filter(language__name__icontains='Hebrew')`

You have to specify the field your are searching.